# When to use events versus pass a reference to a parent (PyQT)

Tags: python, events, model-view-controller, pyqt

I'm trying to understand which of the following approaches is better. I'll use `PyQt5` to illustrate the example, as that's the system I'm working with.

We have a Class `ControlWidget(QWidget)` that provides UI components and spawns helper threads that are just workers executing some task. If one of the workers experiences a failure, we want to notify the parent so it can visually update the user and do some other things like cleanup/disable user input.

Approach 1 would be to send an event from the worker that encounters the error and catch it in the parent instance. The worker Class has an `errorSignal` that simply indicates the presence of an error.

```
# The worker class
Class Worker(QObject, Thread):
  errorSignal = pyqtSignal(bool)
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self._running = True

  def run(self):
    while self._running:
      try:
        # do some work here that might fail
      except:
        # notify parent that there was an error
        errorSignal.emit(True)
        self._running = False

  def terminate(self):
    self._running = False

# The parent class
class ControlWidget(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    # instantiate the workers
    self.worker1 = Worker()
    self.worker2 = Worker()

    # connect to the error signal
    self.worker1.errorSignal.connect(self.handle_error)
    self.worker2.errorSignal.connect(self.handle_error)

    # start the workers
    self.worker1.start()
    self.worker2.start()

  def handle_error(self, error):
    if error:
      # clean up worker threads
      self.worker1.terminate()
      self.worker1.join()
      self.worker2.terminate()
      self.worker2.join()

      # notify user
      self.setStyleSheet('background: red;')

      # disable UI input etc
      self.button.setEnabled(False)
      ...
```

Approach 2 would be to make an `error_status` property on the parent, and pass a reference to each child worker, so it can toggle the error bit directly.

```
# The worker class
Class Worker(QObject, Thread):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__()
    self._running = True
    self.parent = parent

  def run(self):
    while self._running:
      try:
        # do some work here that might fail
      except:
        # notify parent that there was an error
        self.parent.error_status = True

  def terminate(self):
    self._running = False

# The parent class
class ControlWidget(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    # instantiate the workers
    self.worker1 = Worker(parent=self)
    self.worker2 = Worker(parent=self)

    # no signals here :)

    # start the workers
    self.worker1.start()
    self.worker2.start()

  @property
  def error_status(self):
    return self._error_status

  @error_status.setter
  def error_status(self, value):
    self._error_status = value
    self.handle_error(value)

  def handle_error(self, error):
    if error:
      # clean up worker threads
      self.worker1.terminate()
      self.worker1.join()
      self.worker2.terminate()
      self.worker2.join()

      # notify user
      self.setStyleSheet('background: red;')

      # disable UI input etc
      self.button.setEnabled(False)
      ...
```

### Events per second limits?

Functionally both approaches will work, however, I suppose I'm worried that if I have a lot of events in my application (I do) I'll overload the event queue and lock up or miss some. I read somewhere that Qt has a limit of about 2 million events per second (although now I can't find the reference). It may just depend on available memory. If I may conceivably reach this limit, isn't it better to try to offload some event handling where possible?

Is approach 2 a better way to handle this type of issue (presuming I've addressed the thread safety issue with my edit)? It does feel slightly *gross* to pass references to parent/child objects all over the place.

Perhaps this is 6 of one, a half dozen of the other? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The second approach clearly isn't thread-safe, and has no other redeeming features. Use `QThread` with custom signals.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've updated the example to better reflect what I'm actually doing - I think this should be thread safe now?

Comment: @tdpu there's really little point in using multiple inheritance with QObject and Thread, since QThread already does the same (remember that both Thread and QThread are the *interface* to a OS thread). Also, no, your modification is still **not** thread-safe, as you're still trying to change `error_status` from the other thread. Besides, are you sure you're going to reach that *huge* amount of event rate? That seems unlikely, especially if you want to have a UI response from those events (and consider that human perception wouldn't realize a difference faster than 50-60Hz).

Comment: @tdpu I'm under the impression that you're trying an unnecessary premature optimization and you're also still thinking that you could use some shortcut to "avoid" signals in some way. Well, you can't. Qt is an event-loop system, it *must* process all its events, and if you are *really* creating so many events then the problem is in your implementation. Also, if your program is going to be *that* time sensitive, then probably python is not your option.

Comment: @tdpu No, it's not, and my first comment still stands. You have no evidence to back up any of your concerns, so, as it currently stands, your question is effectively off-topic for SO (since it lacks a genuine [mcve]).

Comment: @ekhumoro You're correct that the example in the question was not thread-safe, although in this case, it was more due to errors elsewhere in the implementation (fixed in the answer I posted). I believe that the central approach of modifying a parameter that is shared between threads can be done safely. The main redeeming feature of Approach 2 is that it eliminates the overhead associated with signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events cannot be missed, they are all processed and eventually discarded if not handled and/or ignored (which are two related but different things).

Both your approaches have flaws, though.

### Signals

You should not use `terminate()` (the docs [clearly say](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) that it's dangerous and its use is discouraged).

QThread also doesn't have a `join()` method, it has [`wait()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait) which does the same, but you should *not* use it in the main thread: Qt automatically calls the connected slot in the receiver's thread, and since the signal is connected to `handle_error` (which is a member of an object in the main thread) the result is that it will block the main thread until the thread has actually finished execution. To avoid that, `wait()` *must* be executed in the worker thread, so you can eventually consider a two-signal approach: first react to the error signal, then do something until the thread's `finished()` signal is finally emitted.

### Flag setter

Doing this would only partially work, since the setter is called from the worker thread, so `wait()` will be correctly called from there. Unfortunately, you're also trying to access the UI in the same function, which is forbidden since UI elements are not thread safe. Best case scenario, you'll have some graphic artifacts and some widgets won't be properly updated; worst (and more likely, especially due to `setStyleSheet()`) case, the program will crash.

---

Signals are the only proper and safe way to communicate with the main thread, since they allow correct event handling and prevent freezing of the UI while waiting for the thread to quit.

If you need to change something in the UI when something else happens in a thread, create a function in an object that resides in the main thread and connect it to the appropriate signal that will be emitted from the other thread. If you need to do something that is potentially blocking while waiting for the thread, do it in that thread.

Comment: Sorry @musicamante I was trigger happy with my `Q`s. I'm actually using the `Thread` class from `threading` although perhaps I should move to `QThread`, since I'm creating a Qt application. That said, your comments are still valid. I intentionally simplified the code to try to focus on the event vs flag-setter approach.

Comment: I can see now simplifying (read: being lazy in my example) has introduced more confusion. I will try to edit later today when I get a chance.

Comment: @tdpu You cannot create Qt signals with classes that do not inherit from QObject. While there are ways to work with non-Qt threads and the UI, they're generally discouraged. As said, the proper and safe way to use inter thread communication is using signals and slots, so, unless you have very specific limitations, you should use QThreads and custom signals.

Comment: sorry - just sloppy on my part. I've updated the example to reflect that the worker class does in fact inherit from `QObject` as well (Probably would be better to inherit `QThread`, but this is where I'm at right now). My main concern is that I'm using Qt events to do some high frequency data updates elsewhere, and I'll flood the event queue and cause the application to stutter or crash, or screw up some time-sensitive portion of execution. Perhaps I'm orders of magnitude away from that possibility or I should instead deal with replacing those other high frequency events.

Comment: @tdpu It seems to me that you're trying to do some premature optimization, which is often the cause of problems that not only don't exist, but will also probably never occur. So, you're probably asking the wrong question here. The point, still, remains: if you want to work with threads, you *must* use signals. You might try to use custom events with `postEvent()` but that wouldn't change that much and, considering you'd need to implement an event filter for that *on the python side*, you might end up with even worse results.

Comment: That's fair. I'm trying to consider optimization reasonably early, so I don't get pidgeon-holed later, but it's all a work-in-progress. It may turn out that I've got the wrong tool with Python, but it's a trade-off between system performance and speed/simplicity of development. Ultimately, I think in this case signals are the right thing to do, but it seems like the alternative thread-safe version (in my posted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70658809/13752965) is also viable. Maybe there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: @tdpu as said, 99% of times premature optimization leads to unnecessary development and complications, which often results in making further implementation more complex than it should be, especially if done under wrong assumptions (like in your case, since the second approach in your answer is the same as it is in the question, and is still *not* thread safe). It's unlikely that you'll actually reach that 2000000 event rate and the UI wouldn't react at the same speed anyway, so you should instead reconsider how that rate actually should affect the UI and think about ways to "group" signals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer to my own here based on helpful comments from @ekhumoro and @musicamante, as well as some further digging I've done.

My main pushback is that it seems like the suggestions so far maintain that the *only* way to communicate data between threads is via signals. While this may be the best choice in many/most cases, and a good rule of thumb, there are other safe ways to do it. The reason I continue to beat this possibly dead horse is that in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) it mentions a limit on the number of signals:

*On an i586-500, you can emit around 2,000,000 signals per second connected to one receiver, or around 1,200,000 per second connected to two receivers.*

Granted the hardware suggested here is dated and the current Qt version documentation makes no such reference. However, signals do impart additional overhead vs a normal callback (this is noted in both past and present versions of Qt docs). While this limit is unlikely to be reached in my case, I'm now more interested in understanding both approaches merits and drawbacks.

I think both approaches can be used in a thread-safe manner, although that wasn't properly addressed in the original question. Both approaches are posted here with full MWE.

### Approach 1: Using Signals

```py
# thread-signal.py

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from threading import Thread
import time

# The worker class
class Worker(QObject, Thread):
    errorSignal = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self, id=""):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id
        self._running = True

    def run(self):
        while self._running:
            try:
                # do some work here that might fail
                time.sleep(2)
                raise ValueError(f"Worker Failure")
            except:
                # notify parent that there was an error
                print(f"Worker {self.id} failed")
                self.errorSignal.emit(True)
                self._running = False

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False

# The parent class
class ControlWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        # set up UI
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("Test")
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        
        # instantiate the workers
        self.worker1 = Worker(id=1)
        self.worker2 = Worker(id=2)
    
        # connect to the error signal
        self.worker1.errorSignal.connect(self.handle_error)
        self.worker2.errorSignal.connect(self.handle_error)
    
        # start the workers
        self.worker1.start()
        self.worker2.start()


    def handle_error(self, error):
        if error:
            # clean up worker threads
            self.worker1.terminate()
            self.worker2.terminate()
    
            # notify user
            self.button.setStyleSheet('background: red;')
    
            # disable UI input etc
            self.button.setEnabled(False)

            print(f"Worker 1 isAlive = {self.worker1.is_alive()}")
            print(f"Worker 2 isAlive = {self.worker2.is_alive()}")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    ctrl = ControlWidget()
    window.setCentralWidget(ctrl)
    # window.setLayout(layout)
    
    app.exec()
```

The result of running the example is that after 2 seconds, the workers fail (Worker 1 fails first because it was started first - although this may not always be the case depending on how the GIL is shared between threads). In the end, both workers are shutdown and the control widget is deactivated.

```sh
$ python thread-signal.py 
Worker 1 failed
Worker 1 isAlive = False
Worker 2 isAlive = True
Worker 2 failed
Worker 1 isAlive = False
Worker 2 isAlive = False
```

### Approach 2: Using `parent` References

```py
# thread-reference.py

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

# global thread lock
lock = Lock()

# The worker class
class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, id="", parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.parent = parent
        self._running = True

    def run(self):
        while self._running:
            try:
                # do some work here that might fail
                time.sleep(2)
                raise ValueError(f"Worker Failure")
            except:
                with lock:
                    # notify parent that there was an error
                    print(f"Worker {self.id} failed")
                    self._running = False
                    self.parent.error_status = True

    def terminate(self):
        self._running = False

# The parent class
class ControlWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        # set up UI
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("Test")
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        
        # instantiate the workers
        self.worker1 = Worker(id=1, parent=self)
        self.worker2 = Worker(id=2, parent=self)
    
        # start the workers
        self.worker1.start()
        self.worker2.start()

    def handle_error(self, error):
        if error:
            # clean up worker threads
            self.worker1.terminate()
            self.worker2.terminate()
    
            # notify user
            self.button.setStyleSheet('background: red;')
    
            # disable UI input etc
            self.button.setEnabled(False)

            print(f"Worker 1 isAlive = {self.worker1.is_alive()}")
            print(f"Worker 2 isAlive = {self.worker2.is_alive()}")

    @property
    def error_status(self):
        return self._error_status
    
    @error_status.setter
    def error_status(self, value):
        self._error_status = value
        self.handle_error(value)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    ctrl = ControlWidget()
    window.setCentralWidget(ctrl)
    
    app.exec()
```

The end result is similar in this case, the workers are shut down and the control widget deactivated, but inspection of the output shows an interesting difference:

```sh
$ python thread-reference.py 
Worker 1 failed
Worker 1 isAlive = True
Worker 2 isAlive = True
Worker 2 failed
Worker 1 isAlive = False
Worker 2 isAlive = True
```

The `isAlive()` value of the thread doesn't resolve to `False` until after the `handle_error` method is complete. I'm guessing this is just the way the bytecode execution comes out due to the GIL.

Comment: The second case is expected: as the [documentation says](//docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive), it returns `True` "until just after the run() method terminates.". I'm under the impression that you believe that calling a function of an object that "resides" in another thread results in calling the function in that object's thread, but it doesn't work like that: a function is executed in the thread from which it's called. When you set the flag, the setter (and thus `handle_error`) is executed from the worker thread, and at that time `run()` hasn't returned yet.

Comment: The above also means and again confirms (as already stated in the other comments and in my answer) that the second approach is ***NOT*** thread safe, because `handle_error` is executed in the worker thread, and you can *not* access widgets from external threads. Try adding `print(QThread.currentThread() == app.thread())` in `handle_error` and see the results in both examples: you'll see that the signal example will print `True`, while the flag example will print `False`, meaning any access to widgets (`setStyleSheet` and `setEnabled`) will be done in the *wrong* thread.

Comment: That makes sense. The lock from Worker 1 won't release until after `handle_error` completes and so the Worker 1 thread is still alive when I check. Thanks for all the helpful discussion - I guess this thread went off on a bit of a tangent, but I definitely learned a few things.

Comment: I think there is still something I don't quite grok about the necessity to only access widgets from the main loop. In this case, Approach 2 "works" although it is a fairly simple example with little chance of the code in the `handle_error` method failing. In my definition of "thread safe", I'm assuming that this just means I'm not trying to read/write the same data at the same time from different threads. The Lock (and the GIL) prevent this from happening.

Comment: The fact that it "works" doesn't make it valid. It "works" because a mix of aspects, including the simplicity of what it's done (a basic stylesheet set on a widget with no children and the enabled change): it happens so fast that *luckily* Qt doesn't "realize" that the internal calls are done from an external thread, but there are situations for which even such simple operations could cause problems or even crash. "Thread-safe" objects are called so for a reason: it is *safe* to access them between threads. Widgets are *not* thread-safe. You could do it, it might work, but it's *not* safe.

Comment: See [Reentrancy and Thread-Safety](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html) and [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html), specifically this: "a thread-safe function is always reentrant, but a reentrant function is not always thread-safe" (meaning that non reentrant functions are also not thread-safe) and this: "Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread."

Comment: I maintain that QWidgets are safe with proper use of a lock. In https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html#notes-on-qt-classes they state: "...you can't safely access the same instance of QString from multiple threads simultaneously (*unless you protect the accesses yourself with a QMutex*)." emphasis mine. With PyQt, under the hood `Threading.Lock` and the `QMutex` function the same.

Comment: No, they are not. It might work fine for simpler widgets (that's why some code is able to "change" a widget from external threads without creating issues), but most widgets are *complex*, they rely on the fact that they exist and work on the main thread. Most importantly, there are widgets that interact with or post artificial events to their components, and you have absolutely **no control** over that (for instance, widgets using the QTextDocument interface). There are even styles that install filters and timers for special effects, and that can create even more issues.

Comment: So, the only "safe" thing you can do is to *read* properties (being aware that you don't know *when* you're actually reading it, as it depends on when the thread gets control). Any write action can ***not*** be considered safe, unless you have complete control over the situation and are *completely* aware of the style in use (having studied its source code), the complexity of the widget and the result of that action on it (so, having complete knowledge of all its elements and having carefully studied the source code). Considering the complexity of all that, it's absolutely not worth it.

Comment: I missed the distinction of QObjects and QWidgets, so my previous comment is incorrect/doesn't apply. I do however keep reading things like this: "There are some exceptions: GUI functions that only manipulate data but don’t touch the window manager can be called on secondary threads," (source https://www.kdab.com/the-eight-rules-of-multithreaded-qt/)... which keep nagging me to challenge the "Just don't do it!" message, even though it comes from the official docs.

Comment: In my example above, the stylesheet is updated from the main thread, so I'm trying to understand how the `error_status` property might not be set on the parent `ControlWidget` when called from the worker thread. Still reading...

Comment: Please read that post carefully. They specifically talk about *data*, and they clearly make examples about QImage or QPainter. Almost any action that involves setting a QWidget property will finally "touch the window manager", because they would at least cause a repaint. And I've already explained that the stylesheet is ***NOT*** updated from the main thread, because `error_status` is set from the other thread, which calls `handle_error` **from that same thread**. The fact that the function is part of a class that is in the main thread is completely irrelevant. What matters is *what* calls it.

Comment: When you do `self.parent.error_status = True` you are directly calling the setter function: you're practically doing `self.parent.handle_error(value)` and, thus, the result is *exactly the same* as doing `self.parent.button.setStyleSheet('background: red;')` from the external thread. That's exactly what signals allow: they don't call functions or slots directly if they detect that caller and receiver are on different threads, but instead the signal is *queued* on the receiver thread's event loop, so that the connected function is properly called from its actual (and *safe*) thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243457/discussion-between-tdpu-and-musicamante).